# Multiple Criteria Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to put a validation rule together that makes the Business Reason field required when the Stage is changed to Present Proposal and one of these 4 Revenue/GP criteria is met. Currently I'm being prompted for Business Reason on every Opportunity I change to Present Proposal. Can someone please assist?

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Present Proposal'),
    ISBLANK( Business_Reason__c ),
    AND(
        OR(
            Total_Revenue_rediManage__c > 0.00,
            (Total_rediManage_GP__c < 0.35),
            Total_Revenue_rediTech__c > 0.00,
            (Total_rediTech_GP__c < 0.35),
            Total_Revenue_Product__c > 25000,
            (Total_Product_GP__c < 0.10),
            Total_Revenue_Product__c < 25000,
            (Total_Product_GP__c < 0.05)
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to trip this validation rule only when the record's StageName is *changing* to 'Present Proposal', then you need to check 2 things:

- That the updated value is 'Present Proposal'
- The the StageName picklist has changed

You got the first part of that with `ISPICKVAL()`, but missed the second part. That part's easy enough to do by using the `ISCHANGED()` function (literally just `ISCHANGED(StageName)`).

Your construction of the revenue/GP part is also incorrect. Instead of

```
AND(
    OR(
         <bunch of paired criteria>
    )
)
```

You want to keep the criteria pairs separate (and swap the AND/OR order)

```
OR(
    AND(<criteria pair 1>),
    AND(<criteria pair 2>),
    AND(<criteria pair 3>),
    AND(<criteria pair 4>)
)
```

In your original approach, simply having `Total_Product_GP__c` < 0.05 would be enough to trip that part of the validation rule (even if `Total_Revenue_Product__c` > 25000)

In this new approach, both `Total_Product_GP__c` and `Total_Revenue_Product__c` are considered *together*, so only if both parts are true (Total_Revenue_Product__c < 25000 and Total_Product_GP__c < 0.05) will that part of the validation trip.

There are likely some other boundary conditions you need to consider (if `Total_Revenue_Product__c` = 0, do you really want to be checking the value of `Total_Product_GP__c`? I suspect not), but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Like this? AND(
ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Present Proposal'),ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISBLANK( Business_Reason__c ),


OR(
AND(
Total_Revenue_rediManage__c > 0.00,
Total_rediManage_GP__c < 0.35),
AND(
Total_Revenue_rediTech__c > 0.00,
Total_rediTech_GP__c < 0.35),
AND(
Total_Revenue_Product__c > 25000,
Total_Product_GP__c < 0.10),
AND(
Total_Revenue_Product__c < 25000,
Total_Product_GP__c < 0.05)))

Comment: The rule is still firing on all Opportunities when the stage changes to Present Proposal. It should only be firing when one of the criteria pair is met when the Stage is changed to Present Proposal. What am I missing?

Comment: @Tammy Yep, that formula looks like what I was nudging you towards. I suspect that my last sentence is now the issue you're facing. If, for example, `Total_Revenue_Product__c = 0` and `Total_Product_GP__c = 0`, then your validation rule will trip (even if `Total_Revenue_rediManage__c > 0` and `Total_rediManage_GP__c >= 0.35`. You need to have some additional way to determine which of your criteria to listen to. That, or perhaps making it so that all of those revenue/GP parts must be true at the same time to require a business reason.

Comment: Wow Derek, I can't thank you enough. That never crossed my mind, you're awesome. Thanks again!!